# Android, transmit a signal using ultrasound

Tags: android, mobile, audio, signals

Please tell me how do I create an ultra sound with an android phone? If you already have a code sample?
Thank you!

Comment: Probably impossible, and certainly device specific.  Most devices will not have a speaker capable of producing ultrasound.  In fact, it wouldn't surprise me if no current devices are capable of it.

Comment: ALso, on the basis that if you are transmitting it, you probably want to receive it as well,  you'll also be out of luck:  the microphones on most phones are just not that sensitive at ultrasound frequencies.

Answer (score 3):

Creating an ultra sound is just a matter of playing a sound which contains very high pitches (small wavelength). Sounds are played through electronic devices by quickly changing the power of an electromagnet which is attached to a membrane which vibrates accordingly (a speaker). Sounds can be played at varying levels of granularity, but some speakers may be able to keep up with the signal sent much better than others.

You can construct an artificial wave that thrashes the power quickly from high to low, and any given device will probably reproduce that signal with varying degrees of success. The better it keeps up, the closer it will get to the true volume of the signal. If it doesn't keep up very well, you may only get a tiny vibration rather than the large vibration you sent. In other words, you may find that you can produce the ultrasound frequency you want, but it not in a high enough volume to be useful. And it will definitely vary by device.

Also, it should be noted that ultrasound just means something that is a higher pitch than we can hear. Some people (particularly teenagers) can hear much higher pitches than others. So there is some wiggle room in the definition of ultrasound. But ultimately, these phones' speakers are optimized for playing sounds that we can all hear, and the higher you try to stretch the equipment outside of its intended range, the more limitations you are likely to find in its performance.

If you want to experiment, look up the specs on different sound formats. I think .wav may be the one that you will find the simplest, and therefore the easiest to experiment with. Then construct your sound file according to that spec to make large, fast waves. For example, if the signal power ranges from 0 to 255, you can try a pattern like 0, 127, 255, 127, 0, 127, 255, etc. or even just try 0, 255, 0, 255, 0, which would be one octave higher. And see if you can record something of that wave on another device. (Because you aren't going to hear it with your ear.)

By the way, you will also find that that simply producing the signal is the easy part. If you want to "transmit", then your other device is going to have to hear the signal. But of course, what it actually hears will be mixed with all of the back ground noise in the room, so separating that one frequency from the rest of the noise involves some math. You'll need to get familiar with terms like Fourier Transform. The math is out there. It has already been worked out. But you'll have to work out how to apply that complex math to the problem of sorting out when this frequency is being heard. If you love math, this will be a fun project.

Answer (score 2):

Modern Android devices support a sampling frequency of 48 kHz, so theoretically you could transmitt ultrasounds in the 19-24 kHz range. Now, due to the presence of an antialiasing filter in the microphone's input your actual range is restricted to 19-20.5 kHz and on some devices to 19-21 kHz. If what your looking for is transmitting an ultrasonic tone, then it is very easy. For instance:

```
    int samplingFreq = 48000;
    int numberOfSamplesXSymbol = 48000; //1 sec tone
    int f0 = 20000;//ultrasonic tone

    for (int i=0;i<numberOfSamplesXSymbol;i++)
    {
        tone[i] = Math.cos(2*pi*f0/samplingFreq*i);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

This is more advanced, but it hints at an ultrasound capability for some devices. Android has a "nearby API" that uses ultrasonic sound exchange to pair devices:

> Nearby uses a combination of Bluetooth, Bluetooth Low Energy, Wi-Fi
>   and an ultrasonic modem to communicate a unique-in-time pairing code
>   between devices. The server facilitates message exchange between
>   devices that detect the same pairing code.

https://developers.google.com/nearby/messages/overview?hl=en

Answer (score 1):

You can do it, but you will be limited by the hardware capacities, specially on the microphone side.

Take a look at this blog post which explains more and has an implementation in JS using the Web Audio API. http://smus.com/ultrasonic-networking/

Comment: Strcitly reading, the question is about generating, not about recording or detecting. Please elaborate the role the microphone plays in this in your opinion. Or clarify your assumptions with a comment on the question.

Comment: This is the only correct answer. All other answers are confusing sound generation with sound detection. Microphone and sampling rates have nothing to do with the question of generating a sound. The speakers and energy do.

Answer (score -1):

The phone's speaker can reproduce a maximum frequency of 18-20 kHz. Ultrasound - this is the frequency above 20 kHz. It is impossible to generate ultrasonic signal.

Comment: I assume that your reference is some sort of standard spec for mobile devices or speakers or something? Remember that such a spec will refer to what the device can reliably produce. It does not mean that anything beyond that is impossible.

Comment: @Mark: If you output sound to the loudspeakers it will almost certainly get resampled to native sampling rate of the hardware codec (which usually is 48 kHz). The resamplers I've seen used for this have had a sharp roll-off in their frequency response at around 18-20 kHz. Then again, the OP never said anything about _playing_ ultrasonic audio.

Comment: @ Plo_koon -  Is it possible to receive ultrasonic sound via phone's mic! you have any idea whats the min an d max frequency that we can receive using phone's mic considering we are talking about high end phones and a ball park no. would do